Sending "Start" Live Activity Notification from Apple Push Notifications Console successfully received by APNs and device, but doesn't start activity
Resorting to asking here since it seems that there's not a lot of documentation around debugging "Start" push notifications for Live Activities.
Basically, I've been trying to send a test "start" push notification from the Apple Push Notifications Console, and I am able to successfully send notifications where the console says "Received by APNS Server" and "Successfully delivered to the target device". However the problem is that the Live Activity never actually gets started.
I figured it could be an issue in the client code, and from my understanding, my didReceiveRemoteNotification function should run after it gets received. However, no logs from that function get run.
To further narrow down the issue, I then investigated in the console.app and under liveactivitiesd I noticed 2 errors: Incoming message does not contain usable attributes and Incoming message could not be parsed: <APSIncomingMessage: 0xXXXXXXXXX>
I know my ContentState matches the content state I send in the payload, so I'm not sure what else could be wrong for parsing.
Does anyone know what could be going on? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Verify Notification Payload Structure by Correct Payload Format: The push notification payload should contain an aps dictionary with the usual fields (e.g., alert, content-available, etc.), but it should also include a Live Activity-specific key called activity that contains the type and the attributes required for thLive Activity.
